# Simple Radon-Nikodym derivative property

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a question related to Lebesgue Integration Theory.

The Radon-Nikodym derivative is defined as follows:
If $\mu$ and $ν$ are two $σ-$finite measures on $(Ω, F)$, such that $ν ≪ \mu$, then there is a non-negative $F$-measurable function $ρ$ such that
$$ν(E) = \int_{E}ρd\mu $$for every $E \in F$

($ν ≪ \mu$ means absolute continuity of $ν$ with respect to $\mu$).
Moreover $ρ$ is unique up to $\mu-$almost everywhere denoted by $\frac{dν}{d\mu}$.

The lecture notes say that the following is a routine computation:
Suppose $\mu$ and $ν$ are two $σ-$finite measures on $(Ω, F)$, such that $ν ≪ \mu$. Let $f$ be an $F-$measurable function. Then $f$ is integrable with respect to $ν$ if and only if $f\frac{dν}{d\mu}$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$ but I can't really how this follows. Also, I'd be glad if you could explain the difference between almost averywhere and $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown that for a nonnegative measurable $f$ we have in this context:$$\int fd\nu=\int f\rho d\mu\tag1$$

---

If $f\rho$ is integrable wrt $\mu$ then:$$\int f_+d\nu=\int f_+\rho d\mu=\int(f\rho)_+d\mu<\infty$$
Likewise we find that $\int f_-d\nu<\infty$ and conclude that $f$ is integrable wrt $\nu$.

If conversely $f$ is measurable and integrable wrt $\nu$ then: $$\int(f\rho)_+d\mu=\int f_+\rho d\mu=\int f_+d\nu<\infty$$
Likewise we find that $\int(f\rho)_-d\mu<\infty$ and conclude that $f\rho$ is integrable wrt $\mu$.

---

The term "almost everywhere" is used if it is clear from context which measure this concerns. In this situation that is not quite obvious because two measures ($\mu$ and $\nu$) are involved.

Comment: Thanks! So we can say that the chain rule works for measures, too?

Comment: Do you mean generalization $(1)$? If so then: yes. If not then what do you mean by chain rule?

Comment: $dv=\frac{dv}{d\mu}d\mu$ is essentially the chain rule, right

Comment: How can one show $(1)$?

Comment: @андрэ First prove it for indicator
functions $1_A$ where $A$ is measurable. Then for nonnegative
measurable functions with finite image (so taking form $a_{1}1_{A_{1}}+\cdots+a_{n}1_{A}{}_{n}$
where $a_{i}\geq0$ and $A_{i}$ measurable). Then for nonnegative
measurable functions $f$ making use of $\int f=\sup\left\{ \int g\mid g\text{ measurable, nonnegative and with finite image}\right\} $.
Then for integrable $f=f_{+}-f_{-}$ where $f_{+},f_{-}$ are nonnegative
and measurable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the case of indicator functions is the proof of Radon Nikodym theorem right? Thanks.

Comment: @андрэ Yes. The indicator functions are dealed with in Radon-Nikodym and form the basis of the proof I sketched.

Comment: How to you actually show that $(1)$ holds for a nonnegative measurable function $f$? I've already shown that it holds for simple functions

Comment: Let $(s_n)_n$ be a sequence of simple functions with $s_1\leq s_2\leq\cdots\leq f$ and $s_n\uparrow f$. Then by monotone convergence theorem $\int fd\nu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int s_nd\nu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int s_n\rho d\mu=\int f\rho d\mu$.

Comment: Well done, good person on the internet! That's what you wanted (ish) to hear, right? :)

Comment: @asdf Thank you. Yes I like to hear that. From my Creator, but also from fellow men.